# can i connect star connected motor in delta on same voltage?

Tags: motor, delta

My question is , is it possible to connect **star connected motor in delta**  configuration keeping the voltage same ? if yes in what case ?

Comment: I think you need to list way more information about your problem, please provide a diagram of your setup, voltages and motor ratings. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and I'm sure it has been done. The question, I presume, is can you do it without damage.

1. Read the motor winding max voltage from the rating plate.
2. Read the phase to phase voltage.
3. If (1) > (2) then yes.
4. If (1) < (2) then no.

Comment: thank you it was really helpful , can you provide me with some formulas so that i can check what current my motor will draw at certain voltage for delta and star one by one?

Comment: No. You will find many articles on this on the web and standard text books. Current will, of course, depend on load.

Comment: Motor rating plates give rated operation voltage. Operation either above or below rated voltage is problematic. If the motor can be connected either star or delta, it has two voltage ratings for continuous operation one for star and one for delta. You must connect the motor in the configuration that matches the supply voltage. If neither matches within about 5%, the motor is unsuitable for the supply.